# how to change Chip Background and Stroke color in android with opacity

Tags: android, xml, android-chips

I want to change com.google.android.material.chip.Chip background with alpha but when I set

```
app:chipBackgroundColor="#6F000000"
```

that not work and always have a white background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find the solution in this [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/367). chips have a white surface layer underneath their background and you can set the transparent color for that with this :

```
app:chipSurfaceColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: can you add the guide to do it because I tried it but it fails with me